# Utilizar o operador PIVOT sem agregação

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pivot

Tenho a Tabela FALTAS com as seguintes colunas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FALTAS](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Matricula] [int] NOT NULL,
[Dia] [date] NOT NULL,
[Situacao] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_FALTAS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Dados:

```
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(31,'2014-06-11','FALTA');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(31,'2014-06-13','PRESENTE');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(31,'2014-06-12','FALTA');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(140,'2014-06-12','PRESENTE');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(140,'2014-06-11','PRESENTE');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(140,'2014-06-13','CURSO');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(200,'2014-06-11','CURSO');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(200,'2014-06-12','FALTA');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(200,'2014-06-13','PRESENTE');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(217,'2014-06-12','PRESENTE');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(217,'2014-06-13','FALTA');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(217,'2014-06-11','FALTA');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(223,'2014-06-11','PRESENTE');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(223,'2014-06-12','FALTA');
INSERT INTO FALTAS (Matricula,Dia,Situacao) VALUES(223,'2014-06-13','PRESENTE');
```

e preciso mostrar como:

```
Matricula   11/06/2014  12/06/2014  13/06/2014
31          FALTA       FALTA       PRESENTE
140         PRESENTE    PRESENTE    CURSO
200         CURSO       FALTA       PRESENTE
217         FALTA       PRESENTE    FALTA
223         PRESENTE    FALTA       PRESENTE
```

Sei que o operador PIVOT muda a posição da informação de linha para a coluna, porém não consegui encontrar nenhum exemplo sem a utilização de agregador(SUM,COUNT,etc)

Comment: Uma saída nestes caso é usar um MAX, "dá uma volta" , digamos assim, pois é funcão de agregação.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples

Comment: @Motta, os exemplos que você me enviou me ajudaram, mas vou ter que montar uma consulta que faça de forma dinâmica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a Dica do MOTTA:

```
SELECT  Matricula,
    MAX( CASE Dia WHEN '2014-06-11' THEN Situacao ELSE '' END ) Dia11,
    MAX( CASE Dia WHEN '2014-06-12' THEN Situacao ELSE '' END ) Dia12,
    MAX( CASE Dia WHEN '2014-06-13' THEN Situacao ELSE '' END ) Dia13
FROM FALTAS
group by Matricula
```

Utilizando a Dica do site [Debulhado](http://debulhado.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/pivot-no-sql-server-parte-ii/#comments)

```
declare @values as nvarchar(max)
SELECT  @values = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
'],[' + CONVERT(varchar(30),Dia,103)
FROM    FALTAS
ORDER BY '],[' + CONVERT(varchar(30),Dia,103)
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '') + ']'
declare @query as nvarchar(max)
set @query = 'Select Matricula, |@
from
(
Select Matricula,CONVERT(varchar(30),Dia,103) as Dia,Situacao from FALTAS
) PT
PIVOT
( MAX(Situacao) for Dia in ( |@ )) pvt'
set @query = REPLACE(@query,'|@',@values)
exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

Se a sua tabela de **Faltas** tiver o identificador dessa linha, dá para usar assim:

***Modelo da Tabela*** (`Create Table`)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Faltas](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Data] [date] NULL,
    [Local] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Situacao] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Faltas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

***SQL exemplo:***

```
SELECT Nome, 
       Local, 
       [1] as [13/06/2014],
       [2] as [14/06/2014],
       [3] as [16/06/2014]
FROM Faltas
PIVOT (MAX(Situacao) for Id  in ([1],[2],[3])) p order by 1
```

***Exemplo:*** [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dbb2/1)

Comment: estou tentando utilizar o operador MAX, no futuro terei que buscar o nome das colunas dinâmicamente, no momento quero entender o conceito.