# Converter Coluna em Linhas Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Bom dia!
Preciso que o resultado desse SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CD_ITEM_PAI,
    CD_ITEM_FILHO
FROM ESTRUTURA
WHERE CD_ITEM_PAI = 707534
```

Que no momento é esse:

[image: resultado sql]

Seja assim:

[image: novo_sql]

Podem me ajudar?

Utilizando o PIVOT não obtive o resultado, pois as funções COUNT, SUM, etc.. não servem no meu caso.

Comment: Pesquise por PIVOT.

Comment: isso ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224886/using-pivot-oracle

Comment: Gostaria do resultado. Tentei fazer com o PIVOT mas não consegui. Sei que é simples, por isso queria a resposta para aprender.

Comment: Para colunar acho complicado pois não se sabe o número de colunas ,  numerando as colunas com rownum e fazendo um case com max daria mas teria a questão da quantidade de colunas   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22074/utilizar-o-operador-pivot-sem-agrega%C3%A7%C3%A3o ,  ou tente o LISTAGG https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php